# Indexing non-continous time-series from a dataset/datarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I want to select data from my dataset for the corresponding values in my time-series. The dates in the time series are not-continous. So, I can't use slice with `sel`. Here is how the index of my dataset looks like

```
ds.indexes
>longitude:Float64Index
>time: DatetimeIndex
```

For a Pandas data frame, if I had a time-based index then I could simply use label-based indexing like

```
df.loc[['1979-01-09 00:00:00', '1979-01-09 06:00:00']]
```

Xarray indexing is based on Pandas but I don't know how to implement the above approach

```
ds.var1.loc[['1979-01-09 00:00:00', '1979-01-09 06:00:00']]
>KeyError: "not all values found in index 'time'"
```

I also tried:

```
ds.var1.sel(dict(time=('1979-01-09 00:00:00', '1979-01-09 06:00:00')))
>TypeError: Cannot convert input [('1979-01-09 00:00:00', '1979-01-09 06:00:00')] of type <class 'tuple'> to Timestamp
```

It would be great to know how I can make this work both with `.loc` and `sel` method

Comment: One way around is to convert my dataarray into a `pandas` dataframe and then using `df.loc` method works but probably it's less clean for a large dataset. So, I would like to know how I can do solely with `xarray` indexing.

Comment: Are you sure indexing a DataFrame indexed by a DatetimeIndex works with a list of strings?  With pandas 0.24.0 I seem to get a similar error.

Comment: Yes, I checked again. It works with indexing it as a string in Pandas DataFrame in v 0.24.2 using `.loc`

Comment: Yes, a single string will work (though this has a slightly different meaning than converting a string to a datetime object.  A single string can represent a range of dates; see [partial datetime string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) for examples).  As far as I know pandas does not automatically convert a list of strings to datetime objects as in my answer below.

Comment: @spencerkclark In the link, they haven't used `.loc` method. I checked again, indexing with dict method doesn't work for a list of string but it works using `.loc` method if the string exactly matches the characters of the DateTimeIndex
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to convert the strings to datetime objects first. [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) should do the trick:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

times = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=3, freq='MS')
da = xr.DataArray(range(3), coords=[times], dims=['time'], name='a')
result = da.sel(time=pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-01', '2000-03-01']))
```

Comment: This didn't occur to me and it was rather simple, thanks

Comment: Could you link me to the code of `sel` method? I would like to learn what it is doing under the hood. I tried to look it up on GitHub but I'm new to it and couldn't find it

Comment: Sure thing, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/fad6d624f0716657f903f5955f16422d97275407/xarray/core/dataset.py#L1667-L1735).